# Sorting INT variables C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, rank

I am just beginning with programming in c#;

I got a list of int variables that I want to sort, and find the number 1.

```
int Weapon_Count1, Weapon_Count2, Weapon_Count3, Weapon_Count4, Weapon_Count5, Weapon_Count6, Weapon_Count7, Weapon_Count8, Weapon_Count9
```

do I need to do this with an array?

By using the yellow book of C# I found out how to make an array, but I can't figure out how to assign the variables to the array.

```
int [] Weapon_Count = new int [11]  ;
for ( int i=0; i<11; i=i+1)
{
Weapon_Count [i] =  ??? ;}
```

I hope this does make sense..

Comment: int[] weapons = { Weapon_Count1, Weapon_Count2, Weapon_Count3, Weapon_Count4, Weapon_Count5, Weapon_Count6, Weapon_Count7, Weapon_Count8, Weapon_Count9 };

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this, assuming there is a finite list of variables to check, would be to throw them into a temporary array and call either `Max()` or `Min()` from the `System.Linq` namespace.

```
int maxCount = new int[] { Weapon_Count1, Weapon_Count2, Weapon_Count3, Weapon_Count4, Weapon_Count5, Weapon_Count6, Weapon_Count7, Weapon_Count8, Weapon_Count9 }.Max(); // or .Min()
```

**EDIT**

If you still want to get those variables into an array, I would recommend using a `System.Collections.Generic.List` which has a dynamic size and helper methods such as `.Add()` to simplify things. Lists can also be used with Linq functions similar to the first part of my answer. See [Dot Net Perls](https://www.dotnetperls.com) for some really good examples on different C# data types and functions.

**EDIT 2**

As @kblok says, you'll want to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file to gain access to the functions such as Max and Min. If you want to try using the List type, you'll need to add `using System.Collections.Generic;` as well. If you're in Visual Studio 2017 (maybe 2015 as well?) you can type out the data type and then hit `Ctrl + .` to get suggestions for namespaces that might contain that data type.

Comment: I get this error: Error CS1061: 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Max' and no extension method 'Max' accepting a first argument of type 'int[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (test)

Comment: @RobJansen try adding  `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

Please let me explain how to use a C#-array.

This creates an unitialized integer-array with 5 elements:

```
int[] a1= new int[5];
```

Assigning values 9,8,7,6 and 5:

(Please note that only indexes from 0 to 4 can be used. Index 5 is not valid.)

```
a1[0]=9;
a1[1]=8;
a1[2]=7;
a1[3]=6;
a1[4]=5;
```

The same can also achieved with just one line:

```
int[] a1= new int[] {9,8,7,6,5};
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
        // Declaring the array
        int[] Weapon_Count;

        // Initializing the array with a size of 11
        Weapon_Count = new int[11];

        // Adding values to the array
        for (int i = 0; i < Weapon_Count.Length; i++)
        {
            Weapon_Count[i] = i + 100;
        }

        // Printing the values in the array
        for (int i = 0; i < Weapon_Count.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Weapon_Count[i]);
        }


        // Same thing with a list
        // Daclare and initializing the List of integers
        List<int> weapon_list = new List<int>();

        // Adding some values 
        weapon_list.Add(1);
        weapon_list.Add(2);
        weapon_list.Add(3);
        weapon_list.Add(4);
        weapon_list.Add(5);

        // Printing weapin_list's values
        for (int i = 0; i < weapon_list.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(weapon_list[i]);
        }

        // This is just for the console to wait when you are in debug mode.
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Dont forget to include the using statment if you want to use lists (in short hand - dynamic arrays that can change in size.)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before we start, you might edit your array to look like this:

```
int[] weapons = { Weapon_Count1, Weapon_Count2, Weapon_Count3, Weapon_Count4, Weapon_Count5, Weapon_Count6, Weapon_Count7, Weapon_Count8, Weapon_Count9 };
```

This means that you've created an array called weapons and it is holding integer values.

After you did this, lets find out which element in your array has value of number one.
To find which value has value "1" we must look at each element in array, and we might do that on few ways but I would like recommend `foreach` or `for loop`, in this case I will choose foreach loop.

```
foreach(var item in weapons)
{
   if (item == 1)
   //Do something 
}
```

This above means, loop throught all of my elements, and in case some of them is equal to number one please do something..

P.S

(I may advice to create one variable which will hold an element which has value '1' and when you find it in a loop assing that variable to that element, and later you can do whatever you want with that variable.. and if you think there will be more elements with value of number one and you need all of them, instead of variable I mentioned above you will create [list](https://www.dotnetperls.com/list) or array to hold all of your elements and also you can do later with them whatever you want to.)

Thanks and if you are interested in this kind of solution, leave me a comment so let me help you till the end to solve this if you are still struggling.